Europass CV content not fitting & exceeding page size

While making europass cv in latex i used \ecvblueitem to make two sections (section 1 and section 2). Section 1 has text around half of the page whereas Section 2 has text exceeding one page.
(1) How can I make the Section 2 to continue from the remaining part of the Page 1 and continue the remaining text to another page?
(2) The text of Section 2 not by itself continue to the next page as can be seen at the end of Page 2 it is exceeding the page size.
\documentclass[english,a4paper]{europasscv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
  \begin{europasscv}

 \ecvpersonalinfo

 \ecvbigitem{Text here}{Text here}

    \ecvsection{Text here 2}
    
\ecvblueitem{Section 1}{

text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3 text here 3}


\ecvblueitem{Section 2}{

text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline

4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 

4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 

 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
 
 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
 
 
  4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
  
  
 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
 
 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
 
  4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here \newline 
  
   4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4 \newline
   
      4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4
      
         4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4text here 4} 


\end{europasscv}

\end{document}


    


